# Global vs local CMake functions for compiler flags

Tags: cmake

In the [online book "Introduction to Modern CMake"](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/), I found the following recommendation:

[Do not use global functions: This includes link_directories, include_libraries, and similar.](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/intro/dodonot.html)

Yet the only 2 use cases I've seen of CMake in are:

- make a couple of libraries and a binary using them OR
- compile  a simple binary
- (fetching external dependencies; testing; file generation - not relevant)

In the first case identical compiler and linker flags are strongly encouraged to ensure binary compatibility. In the second case it doesn't matter.

Then, is the following wrong? If not, in what contexts(use cases) would it be considered wrong, as stated by the quote at the very beginning of the question?

```
add_compile_options( -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -Wfatal-errors ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global CMake configuration has its uses. It’s a nightmare to maintain if you’re not careful with it, and in some cases it’s simply wrong. That’s why all the modern CMake guidelines advise against it. But as always the world isn’t black and white.

You could consider global config if both of the following points are true:

- The piece of configuration in question is truly global to your whole project. It is used everywhere without further modification.
- External consumers of CMake targets provided by your project do not need to know or care about that piece of configuration.

The **first point** is mainly about keeping global state manageable. Set it only in your top-level CMakeLists.txt. The earlier you can put in the file the better. Definitely put all global state before any `add_subdirectory()` to keep it global for the whole project. Then treat it as immutable. That way it’s easy to find and consistent across the whole project.

“Whole project” means that you *do* have a single top-level CMakeLists.txt which is used exclusively to build your project. If you can build parts of the project, bypassing the top-level CMakeLists.txt, you don’t have a project-wide global scope any more.

The **second point** addresses the cases where global settings are wrong. When you create an exported CMake project with `install()` global settings are not exported with it. Because the consumers of your project consume CMake targets all publicly relevant settings must be part of your exported targets.

Compiler warning flags are a good candidate for potentially global settings. They tend to be consistent across your project, but there’s rarely a need for exporting them. On the contrary, exporting can even be detrimental. For example forcing `-Werror` on your consumers might break their build needlessly. But keep the `PRIVATE` flag of target based commands in mind before you make something truly global.